# when I manually click on an input linked to a dynamic datalist the values display. When I programmatically click, the datalist value don't display

Tags: javascript, angular, datalist

I program an angular application and use a dynamic datalist

```
<input id="inputCodePostalId" type="text"  (keyup)="findPostalCode($event)" placeholder="Code Postal" formControlName="codePostal" list="codePostalId" />
    <datalist id="codePostalId">
        <option *ngFor="let code of postalCodeList" [value]="code">{{code}}</option>
    </datalist>
```

the datalist is alimented with values coming from a request

```
  findPostalCode(event: any) {
    let text = event.target.value;
    if (event.which != 16 && text != null && text.length > 2) {
      this.postalCodeList = [];
      this.produitImmobilierService.getPostalCodes(text).subscribe( 
            result => {
                            this.postalCodeList = result; 
                            setTimeout( function () {
                                var elem = document.getElementById("inputCodePostalId");
                                elem.click(); 
                             }, 500)
                      }
       );
    }
  }
```

When I enter 595 for example in the input, the request is made, and afterwards, when I manually click in the input, the datalist values appear, but when I programmatically click as above (see in setTimeout function) the datalist values don't appear

### UPDATE

I added a click listener on the input

```
<input id="inputCodePostalId" type="text" (click)="method1();"................
and 
  method1() {
    console.log('ca passe CLICK');
  }
```

I tried also this

```
  findPostalCode(event: any) {
    let text = event.target.value;
    if (event.which != 16 && text != null && text.length > 2) {
      this.postalCodeList = [];
      const event1 = new Event('click');
      const element = document.getElementById("inputCodePostalId");
      this.produitImmobilierService.getPostalCodes(text).subscribe( 
                 result => {this.postalCodeList = result; 
                 setTimeout( function () {element.dispatchEvent(event1); },   
                                         500)});
    }
  }
```

Comment: 'click' and 'keyup' are two different events, so that may be the issue.

Comment: I don't see what you mean

Comment: the input is listening for a `keyup` event and in the timeout you are firing a `click` event. Its doubtful to me that `findPostalCode` will trigger from the timeout event since it is not listening for a `click` event. Try firing a `keyup` event in the timeout or listen for a `click` event on the input

Comment: If I well understand your comment, I UPDATED the proposition, but it changes nothing (see UPDATE in the first post). I can see the log triggered, that's all

Comment: `findPostalCode` is not listening for a click event so it will not trigger. either change `findPostalCode` to listen to `click` event or have `elem` fire a `keyup` event. This may clarify for you what is going on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: see my updated answer. Is this what you mean ? it changes nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223858/discussion-between-flamant-and-booklyndadcore).